# Will my L298N circuit work and will it be safe?

Tags: dc-motor

I have a diagram below using two DC motors and L298N motor driver, and I just want to make sure whether everything will work perfectly fine.

[image]

Comment: any code? any photo?

Comment: is this photo not accurate enough? and i just want to know whether the circuitry is safe

Comment: This is **NOT** "a circuit diagram" It is meaningless without detail. What does the data sheet say? Unless these are tiny motors AA batteries are unlikely to work.

Comment: i'm sorry, these are dc motors and driver is L298N module, but if i would replicate this diagram into my circuitry, will one motor surely work without fail, and will this circuitry be safe?

Comment: What is confusing is that your diagram shows two motors, but your text states only one. It would have been better to have removed the unused motor from the image, prior to uploading it. Also, please try to fix the grammar and presentation of your posts.

Comment: There are DC motors that can move a truck, what are the actual specs (voltage, current, power) for your motors?

Answer (score 3):

As long as that diagram is an accurate reflection of the wiring on the L298N module and between the module and the Pi it looks okay.

Of course only one motor will be controlled as no GPIO are shown connected to control the second motor.

Be aware that the module has three jumper pin headers.

1. Above the motor power, ground, logic power blue sockets.  **If a jumper is fitted you must not connect logic power to the Pi**.  The jumper provides logic power from the motor power line.
2. Over ENA.  **If a jumper is fitted you must not connect a GPIO to ENA** (doing so will feed 5V into the Pi GPIO).
3. Over ENB.  **If a jumper is fitted you must not connect a GPIO to ENB** (doing so will feed 5V into the Pi GPIO).

To enable a motor you must either fit a a jumper to its enable pin or connect 5V/3V3 to its enable pin or connect a GPIO to its enable pin and set the GPIO high.

Comment: so instead using ENA or ENB, i should just connect to the input pins to control the dc motor and just leave the ENA and ENB alone

Comment: To enable the motor the corresponding enable must be high using one of the methods given in the answer.

Comment: yes so will this above diagram, work safely without fail, since i haven't done anything you've mentioned above. And if i want to plug in the second motor too, i should connect the input 3 and input 4 as well as ENB

Answer (score 2):

Excellent circuit and it would be work. But the only problem is you cannot control the right motor because you didn't connect GPIOs to IN3, IN4 and ENB port.

As described in datasheet, all of ports in L298N can be driven at 3.3v so you just can connect GPIOs to ENA, ENB and IN1 ~ 4.

Comment: The OP states that they only have one motor.

Comment: thank you for your response, so i have edited my post so that both motors would be plugged in, will this work?

Comment: Yeah, that will work